# GridView animation

Tags: android, animation, gridview

I want add animation to every single grid view item. I did something like this in method GetView():

```
convertView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.animation));
```

And animation works, but when I am adding new elements to my grid view, it refreshes whole grid view and all items animates again. My purpose is to invoe animation only when item is created and when I scroll. How to achieve that aim?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set up a map of Boolean in your adapter.
For each adapter pos, check if the position has already been animated.
Something like that :

```
if(map.get(position) == null || !map.get(position)){
   map.put(position, true);
   convertView.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.animation));
}
```

Comment: I was wondering about the same solution, but when I will do it like this, animation won't work during scrolling.